My fn+Q is not working in my Lenovo laptop
My Fn + Q is not working in my Lenovo laptop.
Normally, this will switch between performance mode. How can switch between my performance mode?
I have tried a lot of things but nothing works.

We need to know what you have already tried in order not to repeated advice.

Telling us you've tried a lot of things doesn't help us. Knowing what you've tried so far, specifically, DOES help us.

"I have tried a lot of things" is too ambiguous. It could even be interpreted as "shouting at the pc" or "holding my breath" which obviously wouldn't solve the issue. please [edit] your question and add all relevant steps you have performed to solve the issue. also, if you have an fn-lock option - is it enabled or disabled? do other fn-key combinations still work?

Also tell us which model of Lenovo laptop you have.  Did your Fn key get remapped maybe?

Do any of the answers to Easy way to switch power plan in Windows 10 help?
